# Обратная связи от функций обработки файлов c?

Tags: c, файлы, обработка-ошибок

Задача - реализовать проверку на каждом этапе работы с файлом. Получается только самый банальный пример `f((fp=fopen("test", "w")) == NULL)`
А вот чтение, запись проверить не получается. В первую очередь непонятно, какие из этих функций вроде fwrite(), fputs(), fprintf()... Использовать для этого.
Все они возвращают какое-то значение. Можно ли его записать в переменную и какого типа она должна быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждая функция описана в стандарте - что она принимает, что возвращает. Например, [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) - количество успешно записанных объектов, [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) - неотрицательное значение при успешной работе, и так далее.

Так что вы должны отталкиваться не от того, какие функции использовать для проверки, а какие функции нужны в вашей программе. А уже потом выполнять проверку, соответствующую выбранной функции. Типа

```
int rc = fputs("String",file);
if (rc == EOF) // Обработка ошибки
```

Так что еще раз - при выборе функций отталкивайтесь от необходимой в программе функциональности. Дальше - проверяйте, что именно функция возвращает, а что это означает - успех или неудачу - смотрите в документации..

Comment: А будет ли полным аналогом использование функции ferror() после каждого опреатора работы с потоком?

Comment: Не совсем, если не ошибаюсь. Например, ввод строки вместо числа в `fscanf(..%d` - ошибка, но `ferror()` на нее не отреагирует.